# Burg installation error

Tags: 11.10, installation, burg

I tired to install burg with following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
```

Everything went fine but when i run `sudo burg-emu` instead of showing burg theme it shows

```
                     BURG  version 1.98+20100623-2.3

   Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB
   lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible
   device or file completions.

grub>
```

in the terminal. Now i think that i did something wrong. I think if i restart now, my computer might not boot showing same `grub>`. So, how to fix this? I want to install burg either way.

**UPDATE:**
I restarted my computer but nothing happened. There was no burg menu rather it was same old grub.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/burg/wiki/Troubleshooting - there you might find help. When doing such things you should have a ubuntu cd and know how to ork with it for rescuing. Especially changeroot is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. I think i missed a line.

```
sudo burg-install /dev/sda && sudo update-burg
```

Now it works fine.