# Dual-boot selector like windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

A few days ago, I've installed ubuntu 12.04, and when I load my PC, I get this menu: [image: GRUB].

What I want is to have this menu: [image]

but showing the two operating systems (Windows 8 and ubuntu).

Is it possible to move to that dual-boot interface?

Thanks.

Comment: not exactly the same but yes by installing berg ..You can have many choices for those kind of interfaces.

Comment: My edit was because `Embedded images, as on other web hosting sites the images sometimes disappear ` - Shall add my own answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is installing burg and using it instead of grub , for installing press Ctrl+Alt+t for terminal and copy paste or write the following commands..

for adding ppa:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
```

Update repository:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Install Burg:

```
$ sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
```

Update your bootlaoder:

```
$ sudo update-burg
```

Its Installed now , restart your computer and press F2 for changing theme and F3 for changng resolution

For Customization directly without rebooting second time :

go to synaptic and search for burg and install Grub Customizer if its not installed .It will ask you BURG found! Do you want to configure BURG instead of grub2? press yes.

Install it to MBR to put Burg down as the default (over grub).Accept the default value unless you are booting from a hard drive other than the first one. If you're unsure, leave it as it is.

Now open your terminal and write

```
$ sudo burg-emu
```

press F2 and change your theme,and for downloading and installing other themes google the terms , you will get what you want .

Comment: Thank you for answering too! Like I said in the first answer, I think I won't install burg... If I can, I'll put Windows 8 on the top of the grup list, so it will load by default!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to boot Ubuntu from the second screen (showing Windows 8 and Windows 7). That bootloader will only work with Windows, not Ubuntu.

It is possible to get a nicer looking boot screen, using projects such as [Burg](https://code.google.com/p/burg/wiki/InstallUbuntu). Be warned, however, that modifying your bootloader can potentially prevent you from booting into any operating system on your hard disk. If this happens, [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) can be used to fix some (not all) problems.

**EDIT**:

If you would like to put Windows at the top of the list in Grub, I would recommend using [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer), which I have used personnaly. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo) about installing software from PPAs (Personal Package Archives).

Comment: Oh, thanks for answering! I tink I won't install Burg because i'm worried to do it wrong and destroy my pc... Hahahahah! Instead of this, is it possible to put Windows 8 on the top of the list in the grub, so it will load by default? Thanks!

Comment: @Pyttar I've added information to my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is another tutorial on installing Burg on [How to Ubuntu](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-make-your-dual-boot-better-with-burg).

*(It looks good, but I ain't tried it though)* [image: puzzled smiley]

There is also one, which may work better, based on it [here at AdvancedPcUsers](http://advancedpcusers.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/replace-grub-with-burg-graphical-boot-loader).

And any modification required afterwards to remove excess kernels could be done via [Synaptic, Grub Customizer etc](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1587462).

Comment: Thank you for answering too! Like I said in the first answer, I think I won't install burg... If I can, I'll put Windows 8 on the top of the grup list, so it will load by default!

Comment: Burg is just a theme for grub anyway. Have added another link to installing burg to my question - it looks ALOT simpler.

Comment: thanks! I've used the link you gave me, I installed the packages but when I open grub-customizer, it gives me this error: burg-mkconfig no se pudo ejecutar satisfactoriamente. mensaje de error:
 Generating burg.cfg ...
/usr/sbin/burg-probe: error: cannot stat `/boot/burg/locale'.
No path or device is specified.
Try `/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help' for more information. What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Translating from Spanish could help :-) . I don;t have burg  installed, so either go through `/usr/sbin/burg-probe --help` yourself, or add it to [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the link. Did you run the grub-customizer as root?

Comment: Sorry, here is the error message translated: [Pastebin error code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6495771/). And yes, I think I ran the grub-costumizer as root, because when I ran it, it asked me to put the password, so I think so... Now I'm in Windows, in a few moments I'll go to ubuntu and post some images of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Another tutorial [here](http://advancedpcusers.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/replace-grub-with-burg-graphical-boot-loader).

Comment: thanks! I've used that tutorial and it went very well! The only question I have is that if I delete some OS in this list: [see image](http://screencloud.net/v/jEqM) will I be able to restore them? Thanks!

Comment: Don't remove anything but the older Ubuntu kernels *(find the one you are currently using with `uname -r`)*, but keep at least one spare just in case. You should also be able to hide them using grub customizer. More [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1587462)

Comment: Thanks! I saw the tutorial and there says that I must untick what I don't want to put in the list, but I can't see the place where I have to untick... Also, when I inicialize my computer, it still shows up grub instead of burg! What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: At a guess, I think you need to run grub-customizer as root - you can do this via `gksu grub-customizer`.You then need to run `sudo burg-emu`, and then do as it says at the bottom of [the second turorial](http://advancedpcusers.wordpress.com/2012/07/01/replace-grub-with-burg-graphical-boot-loader/) I linked to. My other guess is, is that this is for modifying the theme to how you like it.

Comment: yes, I've already done this, but it's still not working... Well, if I put 'sudo burg-emu' while grub-customizer is open, it happens nothing. Then I have to close it and run 'sudo burg-emu'. Then there I can change the theme but, when I close it's still not showing it in my computer start. Thanks and sorry for answering so late!

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88921/burg-installation-error) help? Suggests running `sudo burg-install /dev/sda && sudo update-burg`. Also, suggests having a Ubuntu install DVD ready to boot repair...

Comment: I get [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6536613/) error. It says to put a '--force' in the code but I don't know where to put it. Btw, I run 'sudo update-burg' and all went good, but when I restarted de PC nothing happened. Anything to try? Thanks a lot and sorry for the problems :S
And one other thing. In an older answer, I said that I wanted to hide some options in grub-customizer, but I can't see the ticks to untick; they should be next to the names. See [this](http://screencloud.net/v/gZVX) image (mine) and [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2plhX.png) (internet one) I haven't got ticks!

Comment: Due to the amount of problems - it might be simpler to post a new question...

Comment: Well, I think I won't install grub-customizer and I'll leave it like it's now, it's not necessary to put the burg menu. Thanks a lot and sorry!

Comment: No problem! Making your computer look good can be almost as important as getting it to work properly! :-)